# How can I change channel on same device with different user?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I've searched a lot this but I cant find what I need.

### What I did is:

in my app users can log in with parse to my system. And when log in system I set channel with username which a user logged in with that username.

### What I want is:

The problem is when a user log out and different user log in , I want to **unsubscribe** old `username`  and set **subscribe** with new user username. But the problem is the channel is not **unsubscribe** whatever I did. I do not how can I do.

### My code is here:

when unsubscribe :

```
PushService.subscribe(this,"old_user", Main.class);
```

and to subscribe :

```
PushService.unsubscribe(this,"new_user" );
```

but when I look at dashboard on `parse.com` I realized that the channel was not changed

How can I solved this?

**thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

Your subscribe and unsubscribe method calls appear to be swapped. For example, you're using "subscribe" to unsubscribe, and "unsubscribe" to subscribe.

Comment: sorry I mean I use that methods to subscribe and unsubscribe not the exactly order is .